# Navigation bar is not centering my links and I don't know how to do this with flexbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a navigation bar for a portfolio-building project, and I can't get the navigation bar to do what I want it to do.  I want "Who needs a quote" to display all the way on the left, which it is correctly doing.  But then I want my links "Sports, business, politics" to display in the center of the screen.  I've been using flexbox, but none of the options will do this.  Can someone please help me with this?  Here is my code.  Thanks!

```
//js file
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav,NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

import './Topbar.css'
import img from './logo.png'

class Topbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "OuterDiv">
        <div>
        <a class="active" href="/">Who Needs A Quote!?</a>
        </div>
        <div class = "topnavcenter">

        <a href="/SportsPage">Sports</a>
        <a href="/BusinessPage">Business</a>
        <a href="/PoliticsPage">Politics</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Topbar;

//css file

.OuterDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;

}



.topnavcenter {
  float: center;

}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood the question completely correctly, but I will try to answer.  Most likely you need to make the following entry: 
    -ms-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    
 for the topnavcenter block

Comment: Hi @Tara's Lyashko. Thanks! I went out for a second but I'll check that as soon as I get back.

Comment: @Matt123 I understand that my advice did not work. Yes? You could share the code that can be opened for the test, otherwise the task is not very clear.

Comment: Hi Taras.  I am working on putting it into sandbox right now,  sorry I've never done it before.

Comment: HI Taras.  Here is the sandbox.  Can you let me know if you were able to access it?  Thanks!  https://codesandbox.io/live/VOJ269

Comment: I want the sports,business, politics links to be in the center of the yellow bar

Comment: Bro, I'm sorry that I did not answer for so long. If you have not yet found the answer, make another link to the code sandbox because this link does not work already.

Comment: It's all good @Taras Lyashko, I just made the same exact thing that is on the left on the right and I made the right elements invisible.  Thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to center the links. Which one to choose depends on how you are going to style the navigation bar.

**`text-align:center`**

A quick approach for a simple, text-only set of links is to center the contents of `.topnavcenter` using `text-align:center`.

```css
.OuterDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnavcenter {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="OuterDiv">
  <div>
    <a class="active" href="/">Who Needs A Quote!?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnavcenter">
    <a href="/SportsPage">Sports</a>
    <a href="/BusinessPage">Business</a>
    <a href="/PoliticsPage">Politics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`justify-content:center`**

If your plan is to make a full-fetched navigation bar with links styled as buttons, I'd rather go with a flexbox option. You can make `.topnavcenter` a flex container and center its children using `justify-content:center`.

```css
.OuterDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnavcenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="OuterDiv">
  <div>
    <a class="active" href="/">Who Needs A Quote!?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnavcenter">
    <a href="/SportsPage">Sports</a>
    <a href="/BusinessPage">Business</a>
    <a href="/PoliticsPage">Politics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @agrm.  Neither of those options worked.  I think for making a topnavcenter a container option it isn't making the flex container a whole row and fo the text-align: center option the same thing is happening.

Comment: Sorry. If the code snippets doesn’t center the links as you expected, I must have misunderstood what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi agrm, here is the sandbox for the project. https://codesandbox.io/live/VOJ269.  I tried your solution and wasn't able to get it to work.  I want the Sports, Business, and politics links in the center of the yellow bar